# JQuery event-listener for .show('drop', 500) == finished

Tags: jquery, events, show

I am searching for an event-listener, where I can check, if the animation with `.show('drop', 500)` has finished.

I want to use it like this

```
if($('#id').show('drop', 500) == complete){
// do some stuff
}
```

Is there an event Listener for this case?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a callback

```
$('#id').show('drop', 500, function(){
   //do something when the element has shown
})
```

This is taken from the docs

> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete.
>   This can be useful for stringing different animations together in
>   sequence. The callback is not sent any arguments, but this is set to
>   the DOM element being animated. If multiple elements are animated, it
>   is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched
>   element, not once for the animation as a whole.

EDIT - if your problem is that you don't want to have the user interacting with the element while it's showing you could do something like this

```
function elementNotReady(){
    return false;
};
 //attach the events so that if the user clicks the element nothing happens
 $('#id').on("click", elementNotReady);


$('#id').show('drop', 500, function(){
   //Remove the handler when the animation finishes
   $('#id').off('click', elementNotReady);
})
```

Comment: Mhm.. I think this isnt a good solution cause the user can interact via mouseover. So it should be possible that the animation must be finished until the user can interact with the element.

Comment: He is also able to decide to not interact with the element. So your solution would be fire something after the animation in any case

Comment: @blackrafi I think this is the solution that is OK if you want to know when the animation is completed. If your problem is to prevent interactions with the element before the animation completes thats a totally different thing

Comment: exactly that is my problem, the user shouldnt be able to interact before the animation is complete

Comment: @blackrafi i edited my answer so that when the element i sshown is disabled as long as the animation finishes

Comment: @blackrafi in my example i suppose that the element you are showing is a link and so i used return false

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd parameter of the [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function is the complete callback:

```
$("#id").show(500, 'linear', function () {
  console.log("completed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a `callback` function, try this:

```
$("#id").show('drop', 500, function() {
    // do some stuffs.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Most jQuery functions, if not all, can be given a function to be called after something is done. Like so:

```
$('#id').show('drop', 500, function () {
    // Do your thing
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(#id).show('drop', 500,function(){
//do the stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#id").show('drop', 500, function() {
    // stuff to do when 'show' animation finishes
});
```

The final parameter is the 'callback'. This is a function you pass to the `show()` method which runs after the animation has completed.

[**Further reading here**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/show#option-options)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `show();` method's callback?